# Path that stays within a convex polyhedron

Tags: scheduling, knapsack-problems, integer-programming

Let $\mathcal{P},\mathcal{Q}$ denote two convex polyhedra in $\mathbb{R}^d$, which can be represented by a set of linear inequalities.  Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a finite set of vectors.

The problem is to determine whether there is a sum of vectors, where each term in the sum is an element of $A$, so that the sum is in $\mathcal{Q}$, and each prefix sum is in $\mathcal{P}$.

In other words, given $\mathcal{P},\mathcal{Q},A$, the goal is to determine whether there exists a sequence $a_1,\dots,a_n$ such that $a_i \in A$ for each $i$, and $a_1+\dots+a_j \in \mathcal{P}$ for each $j$, and $a_1+\dots + a_n \in \mathcal{Q}$.  The sequence is allowed to repeat elements of $A$ multiple times.

Is there an way to solve this, perhaps with the use of an ILP solver?  I can see how to represent this as an instance of ILP using $O(n\cdot |A|)$ variables; is there a way to represent it as an instance using, say, $O(n+|A|)$ variables?

This amounts to testing whether there is a path that stays within $\mathcal{P}$, and eventually reaches a point in $\mathcal{Q}$, where at each step you can take a step in one of multiple directions (indicated by $A$).  Is there a nice solution when the number of steps needed is large but the number of possible directions is small?

This can model recipes that involve crafting items in a game [1], [2]

Related: [1] [Detecting conservation, loss, or gain in a crafting game with items and recipes](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/125011/755), [2] [Calculating path for most efficient use of consumable items?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/142148/755)